# How do i replicate R ungroup() in python?

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr, pandas-groupby

I want to conduct an ARIMA forecast on some data. I've found a similar implementation with R Studio.

```
group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(mean_pv = log1p(mean(pageviews, na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup() %$%
```

The code calculates the log mean pageviews for each day. So far I've replicated this with

```
def mean_pv(pv):
    logmean_pv = np.log1p(np.mean(pv))
    return logmean_pv

df2 = df_train.groupby(['date']).apply(lambda x: mean_pv(x['totals.pageviews'])).reset_index()
```

`df2` outputs:

```
      date        0
0   2013-05-02  1.919935
1   2013-05-03  1.878428
2   2013-05-04  1.674604
3   2013-05-05  1.709476
4   2013-05-06  1.511085
```

My question is what is the simplest way to replicate R Studio's ungroup function? I want to insert the data computed in `df2['0']` back into df_train in a new column, lets say `df_train['mean.pageviews']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two way `reindex` or `transform`

```
s = df_train.groupby(['date']).apply(lambda x: mean_pv(x['totals.pageviews']))
df_train['new'] = s.reindex(df_train['date']).values
```

---

```
#transform

df_train['new'] = df_train.groupby(['date'])['totals.pageviews'].transform(mean_pv)
```